# Magento discount coupon feature on product page

Tags: magento

I want to have a coupon code generator on product page and whenever a customer enters that code it gets certain discount in the shopping cart.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some kind if idea so that I can set things out.In terms how I should process in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check **Catalog price rules** and **Shopping cart price rules**. You can create conditions for particular products. Thus, the discounts will be applied only the products added to the rule.

or

[How to Set-up a Discount Coupon in Magento](http://keithgreer.eu/pages/2012/easy-set-up-discount-coupon-magento/)

Comment: Want to set a coupon generator and whenever a customer enter that code in detail page He should get discount in cart.